# Embed from liveworksheet without using <script> codes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a website-building platform that does not allow `<script>` tags in the code - it would either delete the code or not run it. Now I want to embed a test from liveworksheet, but the embed itself has `<script>` tags. For example:

```
<script src="/embed/embed.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
loadliveworksheet(1904958,'rklhpfyq',1413,'www',2123490);
</script>
```

The embed doesn't appear on the website. I'm 100% this is because of the `<script>` tags. I want to find a way to **remove/rewrite** or **indent** them inside another tag (`<iframe>` for example?). I'm out of idea on how to do this, please help!